# jaxb unmarshal returns empty hashmap but sets it as null

Tags: java, jaxb

I wrote an XMLAdapter for my HashMap. On unmarshaling an empty hashmap (presented by an empty  array), I initialize an empty hashmap and return it, as seen in the code.

```
@Override
public Map<ServiceAttributeVO, String> unmarshal(ServiceAttributeVOXMLMap serviceAttributeMap) throws Exception {
    Map<ServiceAttributeVO, String> r = new HashMap<ServiceAttributeVO, String>();

    if (serviceAttributeMap.mapElementList == null) { //if empty list, return the empty hashmap
        return r;
    }
    for (ServiceAttributeVOMapElement mapelement : serviceAttributeMap.mapElementList) {
        r.put(mapelement.key, mapelement.value);
    }
    return r;
}
```

One would think that the resulted object would contain this empty hashmap, but in reality the hashMap has value null.

What to do?

Comment: Does your variable r have a value of null after it has been created or after you return it?

Comment: I assume jaxb/jersey will use the value of r as argument for the setter on the member of the object. The variable r will never be equal to null before I return it, it will be an (empty) hashmap. However, on inspecting the object after unmarshaling, the value of the according member (which should be the set) is equal to null.